# Why is the error message not being printed?

Tags: c++

Here is a minimal reproducible example of the problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct MyEx : public std::exception
{
    std::string name;
    MyEx(std::string name);
    ~MyEx() throw();
    virtual const char* what() const throw();
};

MyEx::MyEx(std::string name):
    name{name}
{}

MyEx::~MyEx() throw() {}

const char* MyEx::what() const throw() {
    std::string msg = name + "...";
    return msg.c_str();
}

int foo() {
    throw MyEx("This is an exception");
}

int main() {
    try {
        int res = foo();
        std::cout << res << std::endl;
    } catch (MyEx& caught) {
        std::cout << caught.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I execute the executable compiled with g++, I should be getting: `This is an exception...`, but all I am getting is a newline.

Why would this be happening?

Comment: `return msg.c_str();` returns a dangling pointer - the object that owns the text is out of scope after the function returns

Comment: @UnholySheep Isn't a copy made using the string copy constructor? What would be an alternative to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: It's the copy that is going out of scope. `msg` only exists for the duration of `what()`, which ends after `return msg.c_str();` - You could try creating the proper error message in the constructor instead

Comment: @UnholySheep Is this correct: "Since `msg` is of type `const char *`, and we are returning a pointer to something that we have made on the stack of function `what()`, when we return and the stack pops, the pointer `msg` is invalid memory." That's why we can't access it in main? So if instead `msg` was a string (and say return type of `what()` was a string), then this would work flawlessly right? Since a copy of the object is created in the stack of main?

Comment: That should work, although generally speaking using a `std::string` inside an exception object is a bad idea, as allocations required by `std::string` could throw as well (which would destroy your error handling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to avoid the "dangling pointer" mentioned by **UnholySheep** in the comments is to make `msg` a member variable (but you'll need to remove the `const` from `what`) ...

```cpp
struct MyEx : public std::exception
{
    std::string name;
    std::string msg; // This will stay 'in scope` while object exists
    MyEx(std::string name);
    ~MyEx() throw();
    virtual const char* what() throw(); // Note removal of const
};
//...

const char* MyEx::what() throw() {
    msg = name + "...";
    return msg.c_str();
}
```